# @dev and @title in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, library

When we use built-in library in solidity smart contract, why we need to use `@dev` and `@title` annotation?

My code is like below:

```
/**


*@title SafeMath

*@dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error

 */

library SafeMath {



  /**

  *@dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.

  */

  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {

        if (a == 0) {

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Solidity [Natural Specification (NatSpec) format github](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format) for details

> Solidity contracts can have a special form of comments that form the
>   basis of the Ethereum Natural Specification Format. For a usage
>   example please check [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Natspec-Example/).

Answer (score 2):

> When we use built-in library in solidity smart contract, why we need
>   to use @dev and @title annotation?

For generating documentation like other programming languages. Documentation parser's will read the annotations and generate corresponding  html, CSS files. I'll recommend to write documentation for libraries and contracts because that will help another developer to understand methods and its functionality, instead of jumping in to the code.